# What can I use as a C wire for my new thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I currently just installed the nest e thermostat which replaced  an older Honeywell thermostat for my older oil furnace. I connected the Red and a white wire to the new thermostat and it worked for a while until it died and then realized I need constant power or Common wire. I have a green and yellow wire which runs from my thermostat down to my furnace and was wondering if I could use one of the green or yellow wires for the C wire instead (blue wire seen on furnace does not come out at the thermostat for some reason, may be cut to far into wall. if it’s possible to utilize one of the wires where should I connect it on the furnace is my biggest question? Pics attached

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of any labeling on the primary control (the box on the furnace the thermostat's connected to)? It seems that it's not the original one from when the furnace was manufactured...

Answer (score 0):

> blue wire seen on furnace does not come out at the thermostat for some reason

The blue wire could be broken off inside the sheath of the cable

> was wondering if I could use one of the green or yellow wires for the C wire

If they are not being used for some other purpose then you can, The electrical code is a lot more lenient for ELV circuits like your thermostat than it is for manins circuits.